# PostgreSQL how to restore a blob entry to the file system

Tags: postgresql, blob

I want to restore a blob entry to the file system as a file.

How can I do that with PostgreSQL on Linux?
Could you direct me towards an appropriate solution(s)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this section 32.3.3 of the [PostgreSQL docs on Client Interfaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/lo-interfaces.html) for how to use the lo_export function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [pgsql-fio](https://github.com/csimsek/pgsql-fio) extension that provide basic file system functions.